# App-V Calling an Exe in the VMFS due the environment variable

Tags: appv

I have two question regarding the latest App-V that comes with Windows 10. I sequenced an application which has the following structure:

- Program files\OwnApp\run.ps1
- Program files\Firefox\firefox.exe
- Program files\java (some old version)

Now, I need to run Firefox through my own app/script, which is linked due the environment variable. But by using App-V, the env variables does not point to my vmfs but instead to my local drive. Is there any way, how I can link the PowerShell file to the correct Firefox version in my vmfs but without hardcoding?

```
    "${env:programfiles} (x86)$browser"
```

Besides, in my PowerShell file I create a log file in the app folder. Unfortunately, I get an access denied error unless I change the permission in the program data folder.

```
    Out-file : Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Integration\AD721672-C59B-4FB4-9EBB-E23AD314A95D\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesX86\OwnApp\OwnApp.log' is denied.
```

How I can still write the file without manually changing permisson after installation? Was this not one benefit of AppV that the user has write permisson?

Thanks in advance
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

In the past if I needed the non-virtualized path to an internal location i have run as Get-Package command for something like below. Its less than ideal, but there are worse solutions.

```
$Pkg = Get-AppvClientPackage Interlogix_TruVision_7.1_Prod
"$env:ProgramData\$($Pkg.PackageId)\$($Pkg.VersionId)\Root\Vfs"
```

Also, It looks like you do not have the VFS write permissions box checked in your package. That is the most common reason that you would get an unexpected Access Denied.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Honestly, I don't remember exactly what I changed but now it is working. I think the script was wrong. I also change the log path from the program files directory to the users temp folder. 
Btw. I also noticed that in case some apps are writing in the user's home, the folder also has to be created in the sequencer. In my case Java stored something in the user's home